# Using Processing on Ubuntu. Sound Library runs, makes no sound

Tags: sound, soundcard

I'm running Processing 3.3.5 successfully in Ubuntu 16.04, and have installed the Sound Library. Unfortunately, none of the example scripts I've run make any sound. I know the sound card is working because lots of other programs on my machine make noises.

I used the terminal to install the packages recommended at https://github.com/processing/processing-sound using the standard `sudo apt-get install` prompts.

I have not however installed the recomended 'openjdk-7-jdk'. When attempting to do so using the same prompts I got this string returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jdk is not available, but is referred to by 
another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been 
obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate
```

I'm such a noob that I'm not even sure what is meant by "Point the build scripts to the Java installation".

I don't know if this is the source of the issue or not. If anyone has any tips or suggestions, thanks!

btw, I've also asked posted this question in the official [Processing forums](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/23402/using-processing-on-ubuntu-sound-library-runs-makes-no-sound#latest).

Comment: The feedback from the previous unsuccessful attempt to install openjdk-7-jdk said that it may mean that the package `has been obsoleted`. So I figured maybe it needs version 8 instaed of 7.  I just replaced  'openjdk-7-jdk' with 'openjdk-8-jdk' and it seemed to work.

Comment: Still no noises out of Processing, though...